# |a − b| < δ, |b − c| < δ and |c − d| < δ. How small must δ be so that we are able to deduce from this that |a − d| < ε?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have real numbers a, b, c, d (of any sign) and also we have positive real numbers  ε, δ > 0. Say we know that |a − b| < δ, |b − c| < δ and |c − d| < δ. How small must δ be so that we are able to deduce from this that |a − d| < ε? Clearly show your proof that for this choice of δ, |a − d| < ε.

This is what I have so far. If I am doing it incorrectly or you have suggestions to improve it, please let me know. Thanks!

Proof: Let ε, δ > 0. Choose δ = ε/3. Suppose |a − b| < δ, |b − c| < δ and |c − d| < δ. Then we have,

|a-d| = |a-b+b-c+c-d|

```
  ≤ |a-b| + |b-c| + |c-d| (triangle inequality)

  < ε/3 + ε/3 + ε/3

  = ε
```

Thus, |a - d| < ε

Comment: Perfecto, my friend.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was quite simple, but I have struggled in advanced calc thus far, and so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Good to clarify. Always good.